# textBox autocomplete with large amount of strings c#

Tags: c#, textbox

I have searched lots of sites to solve my problem but I wasn't able to find any. What I want to do is make autocomplete textbox suggestions with 103k strings. I have to add all Polish localities to suggestions. Any help with solving this problem?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What are you using to house the suggestion data?

Comment: Do you have any code that you have started working on?

Comment: No, I dont have any becouse Im trying to use components and properities from Visual Studio. And Im using "CustomSource"

Comment: What technology?  MVC, WPF, WinForms, WebForms...

Comment: Can't you just use a ComboBox to achieve what you want? ComboBox has AutoComplete, and you can set your 103k strings as its Datasource.

Comment: No I cant. Number of rows which I can get is around 3k, and I think it depends on lenght, not rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use some API from third party sending to it the requests.
Specifically in your case maybe can use a Microsoft Service like this
-> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776884(v=vs.85).aspx